# How to check whether a value is already in an arraylist before inserting it in Java?

Tags: java, list, loops, infinite

I want to insert values into a List, but only if the values aren't already in it. My code so far creates an infinite loop because as I add values into the List, the size of the list also increases so there is no way that the terminating condition for the for loop will be met. This is part of a larger program, e is a type of object that extends Point.
Note that:
e extends Point. 
e has a value (in addition to the cor-ordinates that it inherits from Point). 
If List is empty, I'd store e in the list. List is of type e. 
If List is not empty, I check to see if an e with the same point location as the e I am entering exists in the list. I don't check for an e object but rather I check whether the x and y values match. 
Updated code:

```
    List<e> listClosestFirst = new LinkedList<e>();  

    if (listClosestFirst.isEmpty()) {
        listClosestFirst.add(e);
    }
    else {

        for (int i = 0; i < listClosestFirst.size(); i++) {
            if ((e.getLocation()).equals((listClosestFirst.get(i)).getLocation())) {
                // do nothing, move on      
            } // end if

            else {
                listClosestFirst.add(e);
            }

        } // end for loop

    } // end else statement

System.out.println("Closest First Memory: " + listClosestFirst);
```

Comment: This may help...[`LinkedList#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Does this have something to do with the traveling salesman problem?

Comment: If you explain what your doing in greater detail we can help you clean up your code a bit as well.  Or offer code samples to help you out.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with a travelling salesman problem. Here is a summary of my project (the part of it where I need to use the list): 1) I need to create my own class which extends the class Point and also has an int value (in addition to the location). This is e. 2) I need to use a random generator to randomly generate x and y co-ordinates for class e. Class e is randomly placed on a co-ordinate plane. 3) I again randomly generate x and y co-ordinates. If the x and y co-ordinates match with any of the values previously generated, I add the object e to the list. (cont)

Comment: (...cont) However, if an e with the co-ordinates generated is already in the list, then I should skip that and move on. Contains doesn't seem to work for me because it checks to see if an object is already there in the List. I don't want to check for objects but rather, if the x and y co-ordinates match, then I want to skip it. So, in order to use Contains, I would actually have to pass in if (listClosestFirst.contains(e.getLocation())) { 
} which I don't think will work because an object needs to be passed in, not a method of an object. I'm cleaning up code now. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code...perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean exist = false;
ListIterator<e> iterator = listClosestFirst.listIterator(0);

while (iterator.hasNext() && !exist) {
    exist = (e.getLocation()).equals((iterator.next()).getLocation());
}

if (!exist) {
    listClosestFirst.add(e);
}
```

Since you're using linkedlist, iterator is more efficient. Approximately, enhanced from O(n!) to O(n).

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out you can use the method `contains()`.  However it may be better to just use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead of a list as sets require uniqueness by default.

*** Code Sample ***

```
    public void testPoints() {
        Set<E> setClosestFirst = new LinkedHashSet<E>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            //create 100 random points/planes
            //add them to the set
            E anotherRandomE = new E(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() * i);
            setClosestFirst.add(anotherRandomE);
        }
        System.err.println("There were " + setClosestFirst.size() + " unique points created.");
    }

    public class Point {
        protected int x;
        protected int y;
    }

    /* Kind of a bad name for a class...perhaps MyCustomPoint would be better.
       Longer names in Java are usually best.
     */
    public class E extends Point {
        private int plane;

        public E(long seed) {
            Random random = new Random(seed);
            int minPlane = 0;
            int maxPlane = 1;
            int xYMin = 0;
            int xYMax = 10;
            this.plane = random.nextInt(maxPlane - minPlane) + minPlane; // random plane between 0 and 10
            this.x = random.nextInt(xYMax - xYMin) + xYMin;
            this.y = random.nextInt(xYMax - xYMin) + xYMin;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof E)) return false;

            E e = (E) o;

            if (this.x != e.x || this.y != e.y || this.plane != e.plane) return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return plane * x * y * 13;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you still want to preserve order consider a LinkedHashSet

Comment: It is part of a bigger problem so I have to use list.